# Can you put variables into an array whose values change in the array when the value of the variable changes?

Tags: arrays, variables, language-agnostic

```
## Pseudocode
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2
array = { variable1, variable2 }
print array
## output: {1, 2}
variable1 = 5
variable2 = 6
print array
## desired output: {5, 6}
```

Is there any way to do this? 
If there is, kindly post an answer in your language of choice.

Comment: Make-a-list type question. Seems to be *"not constructive"* to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can emulate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int variable1 = 1;
    int variable2 = 2;
    vector<int*> array = { &variable1, &variable2 };
    for (auto i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); ++i)
        cout << **i << endl;
    variable1 = 5;
    variable2 = 6;
    for (auto i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); ++i)
        cout << **i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
1
2
5
6
```

Comment: It's not limited to C++, any language with access to pointers can use this method.

Comment: @Bryan: yes. Additionally, in the languages like Java/C# you cannot store a reference to a variable in an array, you would need to pack them into a container object.

Comment: @Vlad: What kind of containers in Java/C# can hold references to variables?